# IOC container working with asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Is there any IOC container that already implements a controller factory compatible with asp.net mvc 2.0 ....if so i'll move my projects to 2.0 to test...
Anyone know a good reference about it?

Comment: Personally, I don't like Unity but I'll take a good look in contrib....I'll post the results when I Can...any reference article on how to use It?

Comment: I'd recommend StructureMap. Breeze to work with.

Answer (score 2):

We're using `NInject` and it works like a charm, too. I compiled it with MVC2 RTM and it works even with that.

Answer (score 0):

MVCContrib has four different flavors for you ( StructureMap, Windsor, Spring.Net, Unity )
http://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/tree/mvc2/src/

Here is a direct link to the Unity one:
http://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/blob/mvc2/src/MvcContrib.Unity/UnityControllerFactory.cs

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I migrated a project to ASP.NEt MVC 2 using Castle Windsor as IoC container. Been struggling to get areas to work to no avail. Keep getting System.ArgumentNullException exceptions. Other than this, everything works as expected...