# For a simple web application, what service locator library you prefer to use?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-4.0, inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-3, service-locator

For a simple application that use asp.net mvc 3 and .net-4, what service locator application is preferred, with performance concern in mind?

Answer (score 3):

See these questions:

- [IOC container working with asp.net mvc 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926391/ioc-container-working-with-asp-net-mvc-2-0)
- [Good IOC Frameworks to use with asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778438/good-ioc-frameworks-to-use-with-asp-net-mvc)
- [ASP.NET MVC + fluent nNibernate, what IoC tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532233/asp-net-mvc-fluent-nnibernate-what-ioc-tool)

About performance, none of the main IoC containers have performance issues in a web application.

Comment: I read already those questions, and other posts. But as you can see, all of those comparison are at least year old, and none of them take .net 4 into account.

Comment: @stacker: nothing relevant has changed. Any of those IoC containers can be used as a mvc3/.net4 service locator.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at MEF as it's included on .NET 4.0 and there are several implementations of modularity on MVC using it.

Comment: Even for a simple application, that don't use plugins, just IoC? What about performance in comparison to a simpler IoC container?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ServiceLocator for a simple application. It just works out of the box. Like in previous versions of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: And how is this simpler than using an IoC and not suffering the inconveniences of using the ServiceLocator?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In simple application you don't need IoC too. You need rewrite your ControllerFactory to use IoC and it is not simpler.